# When are return values garbage collected?

Tags: python, garbage-collection

I'm trying to understand how the Python garbage collector functions and if there is anything I can do to control when an object is collected. I wrote this test:

```
>>> class Test:
...     def __del__(self):
...         print 'Delete ' + str(self)
...
>>> def fun():
...    return Test()
...
>>> fun()
<__main__.Test instance at 0x0000000002989E48>
>>> fun()
Delete <__main__.Test instance at 0x0000000002989E48>
<__main__.Test instance at 0x00000000023E2488>
>>> fun()
Delete <__main__.Test instance at 0x00000000023E2488>
<__main__.Test instance at 0x0000000002989C48>
```

As you can see, the `Test` instance, although I do not keep an instance to it, is not deleted until the next time I call `fun`. Is this simply an accident (could it have been deleted at any other point) or is there a specific reason why it is deleted only when I call `fun` again? Is there anything I can do to ensure it gets deleted if I don't keep a reference to it?

Comment: Similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17574106/2225682).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try explicitly calling `del` on the returned value:

```
returned_value = fun()
del returned_value
```

But finalizers like `__del__` can be problematic; as you have already seen, one issue is that when they get called is not deterministic. Also, it is possible within a finalizer to reinstantiate a deleted object, such as sticking a reference to it in a global list.

If you need to release resources (besides just raw memory) - things like unlocking locks, closing files, or releasing database connections, use a context manager, and bound its life span using the `with` statement.  Many of these resource are already context managers. For example, a threading.Lock can be locked and unlocked implicitly using `with`:

```
# "with" statement will call the __enter__ method of self.lock,
# which will block until self.lock can be locked
with self.lock:
    # do thread-synchronized stuff here

# self.lock is automatically released here - at then end of
# the "with" block, the lock's __exit__ method is called, which
# releases the lock. This will get called even if the block is 
# exited by a raised exception
```

Comment: `del fun()` is a syntax error, and rightly so because that doesn't even make sense. I strongly agree with the rest.

Comment: @delnan I take it `del` simply removes the reference to the object and it's still up to the GC to decide when it gets deleted.

Comment: @PaulManta Precisely. Which is why it only applies to names and collection items (`del foo[bar]`).

Comment: Thanks for the catch on `del fun()` - too much C++ on the brain!

Answer (score 3):

The "contact" of the Python garbage collector (like all garbage collectors) is that it will release an object sometime after the last reachable reference to it disappears.

Because CPython uses reference counting, as an implementation detail it will release most garbage objects (specifically non-cyclic objects) *immediately* after the last reachable reference to them disappears. This is not a guarantee of the Python language, and is not true of other Python implementations like PyPy, Jython, IronPython, so relying on it is generally considered to be poor practice.

In your case, what you're observing with the object being collected after the function is called again has little to do with the behaviour of the garbage collector, but is rather due to the way the interactive interpreter shell works.

When you evaluate an expression in the interactive prompt, the resulting value is automatically saved in the variable `_`, so you can get it back if you discover that you still want it only *after* you've seen it printed. So after your `fun()` calls, there **is** still a reference to the return value. Then when you evaluate another expression (*anything* else, it doesn't have to involve `fun` again), `_` is overwritten with the new value, allowing the old one to be garbage collected.

This *only* happens for expressions directly entered at the interactive prompt, so it won't delay collection of objects within functions or when your Python code is imported or run as a script.