# Why is the __del__ method not called?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) is what the `object.__del__(self)` documentation says:

> Called when the instance is about to be destroyed

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement) is what the `del` documentation says:

> Deletion of a name removes the binding of that name from the local or global namespace, depending on whether the name occurs in a global statement in the same code block

I've also read many related questions here on SO. I understood that if there are multiple variables pointing to the same object then of course deleting one name will not trigger the object `__del__` method (because there is still a variable referencing the object).

So I tried a few experiments to check if I understood everything correctly. Let's say I have this class:

```
class A:
    def __del__(self):
        print('Object finalizer')
```

Now, this is what I have done:

```
>>> a1 = A()
>>> del a1
Object finalizer
```

Everything works as expected so far: there was only a single reference to that object, so once I delete that reference the object is also deleted. Then, I tried with two names referencing the same object:

```
>>> a1 = A()
>>> a2 = a1
```

Check that the two variables are actually referencing the same object:

```
>>> a1
<__main__.A object at 0x7fef201f4fd0>
>>> a2
<__main__.A object at 0x7fef201f4fd0>
```

But if I now try to delete all references, things do not go as expected:

```
>>> del a1
>>> del a2
>>>
```

I was expecting the `__del__` method to be called after the `del a2` statement. Why is this happening? What am I missing?

Comment: Object deletion depends on the *garbage collector* and *may not happen immediately…*

Comment: @deceze where is this stated in the docs? Could you please provide me with an official reference? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @RiccardoBucco Here is a git repo I found about [this](https://github.com/satwikkansal/wtfpython#-stubborn-del-operation).

Comment: Look at gc.collect: https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.collect

Comment: @U12-Forward Thanks. Well, so my question should have not been closed ... The reason is not that the garbage collector was not called, but simply there is still a reference to my object, namely `_`. This should be the accepted answer, thanks a lot U12-Forward!!

Comment: @deceze Look at other comments, it's not because of the garbage collector, my question is not related to that, I can't understand why people closed it

Comment: @RiccardoBucco I guess, this should be reopened...

Comment: Added more duplicates which already contain this information.

Comment: @Marco Because of further clarifications from [the other dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17574589/476). And even in your referenced dupe, it says *"According to this, Python may be keeping your object in a free list for recycling even if you drop its refcount to zero"*, so generally you shouldn't expect any particular behaviour from the gc.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Because there's still a reference, namely `_`, look at the link provided by U12-Forward

Comment: Yeah found that somehow, a very useful link :) P.S. was in the middle of an answer while closure.

Comment: Wait... I accidentally hit reopen...

Comment: Soory @deceze Edited closed again...

Comment: @AlexWaygood True... Added one, the most important one back, adding more back

Comment: Imo it would be quite nice to have a good answer to this question, since the answer seems to be scattered among several other questions at present.

Comment: @AlexWaygood True... I agree with the reopening though a bit.

Comment: @deceze What's your opinion on this :) ?

Comment: IMO A concrete answer on this q would be very nice.

Comment: @deceze What do you think?

Comment: I think TL;DR: don't depend on any specific behaviour of the gc, end of story. Specific details can be taken from the other existing Q&As.

Comment: I say leave it closed and just keep the dupe target with the `_` answer.

Comment: Yeah I think the one that's currently the third on the dupes list (the one in the interactive REPL) is the most informative one for this question